# Can not connect to a Google Cloud TPU using ssh (putty) in Windows

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, connection, ssh-keygen

I have a google v3-8 TPU, i can't figure out how to connect to it using ssh in windows.
I did every guide there is, but the connection just times out.

What i tried (among others):
1.
Dos command line:
gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west4-a

gcloud config set account myusername@gmail.com

gcloud config set project myprojectname

gcloud services enable tpu.googleapis.com

gcloud alpha compute tpus tpu-vm ssh --zone europe-west4-a vm_name

This just opens Putty which then timeouts.

2. Create a pub/priv key using Puttygen and adding the public key in the (2a)Google Cloud Platform website > Compute Engine Metadata > SSH keys
   Adding the same key to ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub , and private key to ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine on the TPU VM using the web-console of GCP.
   (The key files where empty)
   When connecting with putty it timeouts
3. Did step 1. but with this as the last line.
   gcloud alpha compute tpus tpu-vm ssh --zone europe-west4-a vm_name --ssh-key-file=C:\Users\my_username\Documents\putty_keys\gc
   (there are three files, gcloud adds the extensions, gc.pub with the public key, gc with the private key, and gc.ppk )
   Putty does not connect.
4. Did the reverse, created the ssh-keys on the TPU server using ssh-gen renamed keys to ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub , and private key to ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
   Copy pasted them to putty-gen to convert to windows putty keys, added keys using (2a)
   Connected putty to vm outside-ip and nothing.
5. Created the ssh-keys on the TPU server using ssh-gen adding them to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and installing them with ssh-copy-id and entering password
   Copied the keys to puttygen and used them to connect to VM ip.

I did more to connect, but to no avail.

What is the right way to connect to a TPU VM ?
Note, it's not a Compute VM, it's a TPU. not the same settings as a VM in GCP console, so no nice add ssh key in the edit settings, because there ARE NO edit settings in GCPC.

I'm at a loss.

PS threw away the TPU instance and recreated it after each step, to make sure i wasn't messing things up too badly.

/EDIT:

i fixed it using this batch file

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
SET PATH=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;%PATH%;
cd C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK
call gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west4-a
call gcloud config set account acountname@gmail.com
call gcloud config set project projectname
gcloud alpha compute tpus tpu-vm ssh --zone europe-west4-a username@TPU_VM
```

Comment: 1) Stop playing around with setting SSH keys. 2) Where are you connecting to the TPU VM from? 3) Did you enable a firewall rule for port 22 ingress if connecting from outside Google Cloud. 4) launch a small VM in the same VPC network and connect from the VM to the TPU VM using the internal IP. Refer to the command line option `--internal-ip`.

Comment: 5) Execute this command `gcloud alpha compute tpus tpu-vm ssh --dry-run`. Notice the output. You can then use a Windows SSH client to connect and debug such as Bitvise. Google sometimes does not test commands on Windows enough on alpha release features. Also notice the SSH port number. Edit your question with these details.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed it using this batch file

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
SET PATH=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;%PATH%;
cd C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK
call gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west4-a
call gcloud config set account acountname@gmail.com
call gcloud config set project projectname
gcloud alpha compute tpus tpu-vm ssh --zone europe-west4-a username@TPU_VM
```